# Decrypt file from private key .ppk

Tags: encryption, putty, decryption, gpg4win

I got files from our developer, those files are (private key = file.ppk), (public key = pub.asc), and (encrypted file = file-encrypt.txt.pgp). Person who has created these files has resigned and just give all file above and passphrase. I try to decrypt that file using cleopatra but cleopatra don't know the type of file file.ppk.

How to convert maybe or another choice to decrypt that files?

Answer (score 1):

These keys belong to different programs:

- `file-encrypt.txt.pgp` is encrypted using PGP. How to decrypt it depends on its contents (`gpg --list-packets` might reveal something); you might need just a passphrase, or you might need someone's private PGP key, but I'm 100% sure it has *nothing* to do with the `.ppk` file.
- `file.ppk` is a SSH keypair. It is *not* a PGP key – it's for logging in to SSH servers *only* and cannot be used to decrypt anything. "`.ppk`" means it's in PuTTY format; you can use PuTTYgen to convert it to OpenSSH format for Linux/macOS.
- `pub.asc` can be several things. It might be a PGP public key (usable for encrypting but *not* for decrypting), or it might be a PGP-signed piece of text (e.g. a SSH pubkey). Try opening the file with Notepad, decrypting it with Kleopatra, or importing it to Kleopatra.